# Get XMPP SID and RID from BOSH in PHP?

Tags: php, xmpp, sessionid

How do I extract the SID and RID values used in the [BOSH transport protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html) for XMPP? Specifically, I'm using [xmpphp](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/).

Comment: @user43... I've edited your question to include what I think you mean (helps I've heard of XMPP really). If this isn't what you mean, please edit it accordingly. Welcome to SO by the way - few words of friendly advice for next time: it's best to be explicit in what you mean and including code is even better - it means we can narrow down the options and give you a good answer.

Comment: @Ninefingers nice edit and introduction!

Comment: @Pekka - haha. It's hard to tell exactly where his/her issues are from the question (e.g. what's been tried), but I thought I'd put something other than 'self explanatory' in the box and dissuade down voters because the question *is* valid, if a little vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of work on XMPPHP especially the BOSH part of it (which until recently didn't even work). http://github.com/Wordi/xmpphp

In my case, I'm using it to bootstrap a UI client and provide auto-login capability for XMPP BOSH.

```
class Library_BOSH extends XMPPHP_BOSH
{

    public function getAutoLoginInfo()
    {
        return array(
            "jid" => $this->fulljid,
            "rid" => $this->rid,
            "sid" => current( $this->sid )
        );
    }

    //we want to block saving the BOSH session into our $_SESSION,
    //since we're just using it to bootstrap the UI client
    public function saveSession(){;}

}

$bosh = new Library_BOSH(
    $server_address, $server_port,
    $jid, $password,
    NULL, NULL, FALSE, XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE
);

$bosh->connect( "http://myboshdomain.com/http-bind/", 60 );
$bosh->processUntil('session_start', 5);

$bosh_info = $bosh->getAutoLoginInfo();
```

Comment: giving me error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in htdocs/xmpp/xmpphp-master/XMPPHP/BOSH.php:88 Stack trace: #0 htdocs/xmpp/xmpphp-master/XMPPHP/BOSH.php(88): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8D\x92aO\xC2...') #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xmpp/xmpphp-master/test.php(30): XMPPHP_BOSH->connect('http://192.168....', 60) #2 {main} thrown in htdocs/xmpp/xmpphp-master/XMPPHP/BOSH.php on line 88`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to extract the "sid" and "rid" for your connected bosh client? If yes, generally these are saved in php sessions or browser cookies. I haven't used xmpphp, but you can just try to dump client's session info to see it's content.

Comment: I want to know how I can even connect.

Comment: Well in that case all i can suggest is to try out working BoshChat and BoshMUChat application using Jaxl library (http://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL), i have little experience with xmpphp.